# ORA-06550 LINE 11 COLUMN:3 WRONG NUMBER OF ARGUMENTS IN CALL TO IN BELOW PL/SQL STORED PROCEDURE

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace Procedure CUSTOM_SP_TYPE (parenteqName in varchar2,StartDate in DATE,EndDate in DATE,trgt_type OUT varchar2,prc out SYS_REFCURSOR)
As
Begin

  OPEN prc for SELECT DISTINCT TRGT_TYPE INTO trgt_type FROM   C_MAADEN_DAILYREPORT WHERE (HIERARCHY_TYP IN ('ASSET')) AND (PARENT_EQ_NAME IN (SELECT     EQ_NAME
  FROM IP_EQUIP_HIERARCHY WHERE (PARENT_EQ_NAME IN(SELECT EQ_NAME FROM  IP_EQUIP_HIERARCHY IP_EQUIP_HIERARCHY_1 WHERE      (PARENT_EQ_NAME IN (parenteqName)) OR
(EQ_NAME IN (parenteqName)) OR (EQ_NAME IN (parenteqName)))))) AND    
(SHFT_START_DT_TM >= StartDate)AND (SHFT_END_DT_TM <=EndDate);

 End CUSTOM_SP_TYPE;
```

Comment: please give me correct answer where i am wrong ??

Comment: How can we answer if you do not show **how you call** this sp?

Comment: PLEASE FIX YOUR KEYBOARD. YOUR SHIFT KEY IS BROKEN

Comment: It's difficult to read your code.  Please format it .  Use line breaks and indents.

Comment: You cannot combine opening a Cursor `OPEN prc FOR SELECT ...` and assigning values to variable `SELECT ... INTO ...`. Make two different statements.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong. Working code would be this one:

```
create or replace Procedure CUSTOM_SP_TYPE(
    parenteqName in varchar2,
    StartDate in DATE,
    EndDate in DATE,
    OUT_trgt_type OUT varchar2,
    prc out SYS_REFCURSOR) As
Begin

   OPEN prc for 
   SELECT DISTINCT TRGT_TYPE
   FROM C_MAADEN_DAILYREPORT 
   WHERE HIERARCHY_TYP IN ('ASSET') 
       AND PARENT_EQ_NAME IN (
          SELECT EQ_NAME
          FROM IP_EQUIP_HIERARCHY 
          WHERE PARENT_EQ_NAME IN (
              SELECT EQ_NAME 
              FROM IP_EQUIP_HIERARCHY IP_EQUIP_HIERARCHY_1 
              WHERE parenteqName IN (PARENT_EQ_NAME, EQ_NAME)
              )
          ) 
       AND SHFT_START_DT_TM >= StartDate
       AND SHFT_END_DT_TM <= EndDate;


   SELECT DISTINCT TRGT_TYPE
   INTO OUT_trgt_type
   FROM C_MAADEN_DAILYREPORT 
   WHERE HIERARCHY_TYP IN ('ASSET') 
       AND PARENT_EQ_NAME IN (
          SELECT EQ_NAME
          FROM IP_EQUIP_HIERARCHY 
          WHERE PARENT_EQ_NAME IN (
              SELECT EQ_NAME 
              FROM IP_EQUIP_HIERARCHY IP_EQUIP_HIERARCHY_1 
              WHERE parenteqName IN (PARENT_EQ_NAME, EQ_NAME)
              )
          ) 
       AND SHFT_START_DT_TM >= StartDate
       AND SHFT_END_DT_TM <= EndDate;

 End CUSTOM_SP_TYPE;
```

However, it does not make any sense to open a cursor `prc` and assigning the same value also to a variable. Apart from that, the second query may raise exception `NO_DATA_FOUND` or `TOO_MANY_ROWS`.

Then you should avoid to use the same variables names like column names. `SELECT DISTINCT TRGT_TYPE INTO trgt_type FROM ...` would just assign existing value of parameter TRGT_TYPE to TRGT_TYPE, i.e. it would be equivalent to `TRGT_TYPE := TRGT_TYPE;` which is useless.

This duplicate condition `EQ_NAME IN (parenteqName) OR EQ_NAME IN (parenteqName)` is also useless.

Comment: How do you call the procedure?

Comment: in sql developer Run ,actually i want to used this in ssrs reports so also checked in query designer

Comment: If you don't tell us how you call the procedure we cannot help you.

Comment: I stop any further discussion unless you show us how you call the procedure. - Most likely there is the error.

Comment: what is the exact format for start date and end date  i want to take date as well as time in 12 hours format used this format  (om.shft_start_dt_tm >= to_date(:StartDate, 'mm/dd/yyyy HH12:MI:SS AM') AND om.shft_end_dt_tm <= to_date(:EndDate, 'mm/dd/yyyy HH12:MI:SS PM'))

Comment: in sql developer Right click to stored procedure then Run and then automatic script added parameter like below

Comment: DECLARE
  PARENTEQNAME VARCHAR2(200);
  STARTDATE DATE;
  ENDDATE DATE;
  OUT_TRGT_TYPE VARCHAR2(200);
  PRC SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  PARENTEQNAME := 'DIGESTION OC';
  STARTDATE := '1/1/2016 7:00:00 AM';
  ENDDATE := '6/2/2017 7:00:00 PM';

  CUSTOM_SP_TYPE(
    PARENTEQNAME => PARENTEQNAME,
   STARTDATE => STARTDATE,
   ENDDATE => ENDDATE,
    OUT_TRGT_TYPE => OUT_TRGT_TYPE,
    PRC => PRC
  );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OUT_TRGT_TYPE = ' || OUT_TRGT_TYPE);
  -- Modify the code to output the variable
  --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PRC = ' || PRC);
END;

Comment: Edit your question instead of adding as comment.